# How to solve Import Error on Python's 'Pyzbar' library?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, zbar

I've just started getting familiar with the library Pyzbar, but when using the `decode` method I get an error. Here's the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyzbar

code_image = cv2.imread("C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\qr.PNG")
cv2.imshow("QR", code_image)
cv2.waitKey(0) #this command is to hold the image open after opening it

from pyzbar import decode
decoded = pyzbar.decode(code_image)
print(decoded)
```

qr.PNG is just a picture of a QR Code. OpenCV displays the image just fine but it's the decoding part that doesn't work:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/ML >Projects/Projects/OpenCV/QR_Code_Detection.py", line 17, in 
>      from pyzbar import decode
>   ImportError: cannot import name decode

When excluding this line: `from pyzbar import decode`

I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/ML >Projects/Projects/OpenCV/QR_Code_Detection.py", line 17, in 
>      decoded = pyzbar.decode(code_image)
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'decode'

Hope someone more knowledgeable can help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After wresting with this problem for quite some time and trying different methods  that worked for other people *(Reinstalls, repairs, patches, Windows Updates, setting pathways, renaming directories, importing within a function, using Dependency Walker to install dependencies and so much more...)* it turned out it was a `Microsoft Visual C++` problem and the only thing that I saw on some obscure forum and that worked for me was installing **ALL** versions of Visual C++ *(from 2008 to 2017)* both x64 **and** x86 (or else it doesn't work) and it worked like a charm.

So I'm just gonna leave this here hopefully it spares somebody the hassle.

Comment: Unfortunately this crazy solution is the right one.

Comment: It's pretty interesting that I should install both x64 and x86. Installing only x64 didn't work but installing both worked. Thanks.

Comment: I installed just the 2013 version both x86 and x64 and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

Just installing `Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 64 bit` fixed it for me
(on 64 bit windows and 64 bit python)

link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784

Answer (score 0):

You need to install zbar before using pyzbar

```
brew install zbar
pip install pyzbar
######################################
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
code_image = cv2.imread("barcode.jpg")
cv2.imshow("QR", code_image)
decoded = decode(code_image)
print(decoded)
```