# Could not find module "libiconv.dll" when trying to import "pyzbar" module into Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-lab

My system:

- Windows 8.1 pro , version 6.3 (build 9600)
- Anaconda version: conda 4.9.2
- Python 3.8.5 (python in conda env)
- Jupyter Lab 2.2.6

Hey, I hope you guys have a great day. I have some difficulties when I try to import "pyzbar" module into Jupyter Lab. It says:

> Could not find module
> 'C:\Users\mypc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\ **libiconv.dll**'
> (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor
> syntax.

I have tried to reinstall this package using pip and conda, and nothing seems to be working. I have also tried to install "Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013" (note: I thought my problem is a bit similar to this, [How to solve Import Error on Python's 'Pyzbar' library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55544032/how-to-solve-import-error-on-pythons-pyzbar-library), I only download and install 2013 x64 version, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784) and it still does not solve my issue. Any suggestion or a little bit of help would be great. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2):

What fixed it for me (on anaconda) was: I had installed `pyzbar` via `conda-forge`. I uninstalled it and reinstalled it using pypi and it worked:

```
pip uninstall pyzbar
pip install pyzbar
```

Comment: I also install pyzbar via conda-forge, and occurred the same issue missing the libiconv.dll, the answer can fix this issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try python3.6.2(without anaconda) it working know, [here is result on python 3.6.2 without conda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH9OK.png)

```
~\Projects\Opencv\python\QR-Code-Projects\QR-Code                                                      [  ] 11:46:50
➜ python .\Test_pyZbar.py
-----------------------------
python Verion:  3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:57:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
-----------------------------
Data: Some data
BBox: Rect(left=40, top=40, width=210, height=210)
 ~\Projects\Opencv\python\QR-Code-Projects\QR-Code                                                      [  ] 11:48:49
```

[not working on conda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxMft.png)

Terminal out with conda env (QR-code) python3.6.

```
   File "C:\minconda\envs\QR-code\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
   self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
 ~\Projects\Opencv\python\QR-Code-Projects\QR-Code                                               [ QR-code ] 11:49:08
➜
```

```
import cv2
import sys
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode, ZBarSymbol
print("-----------------------------")
print('python Verion: ', sys.version)
print("----------------------------")
# Image.open('barcode1.png')  # if use PIL library
im = cv2.imread("Code.png")  # if use cv2

# codes = decode(im, symbols=[ZBarSymbol.QRCODE])  # specify code type
codes = decode(im)  # auto detect code type
# print('Decoded:', codes)

for code in codes:
    data = code.data.decode('ascii')
    print('Data:', code.data.decode('ascii'))
    # print('Code Type:', code.type)
    print('BBox:', code.rect)
    x, y, w, h = code.rect.left, code.rect.top, \
        code.rect.width, code.rect.height
    cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 8)
    # print('Polygon:', code.polygon)
    cv2.rectangle(im, code.polygon[0], code.polygon[1],
                  (0, 255, 0), 4)

    txt = '(' + code.type + ')  ' + data
    cv2.putText(im, txt, (x - 10, y - 10),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 50, 255), 2)

text1 = 'No. Codes: %s' % len(codes)
cv2.putText(im, text1, (5, 15),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow('bounding box', im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Asadullah, however my issue is still not resolve, I am going to research more into this, and give any further update, again, thanks a lot!

Comment: Just install python3.6,  libiconv.dll, is shipped in with python 3.6 without conda, have you tried that?    https://github.com/Asadullah-Dal17/QR-detection-and-Distance-Estimation