# Why I am getting error in the pyzbar module while using this library it in the QRCode scanning project?

Tags: python, python-module, zbar

ERROR IS :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P:\Prashant\Python\Attendance\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\zbar_library.py", line 58, in load
    dependencies, libzbar = load_objects(Path(''))
  File "P:\Prashant\Python\Attendance\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\zbar_library.py", line 50, in load_objects
    deps = [
  File "P:\Prashant\Python\Attendance\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\zbar_library.py", line 51, in <listcomp>
    cdll.LoadLibrary(str(directory.joinpath(dep)))
  File "C:\Users\kalep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 452, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Users\kalep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'libiconv.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P:\Prashant\CPP Project Planning\Rooturaj CPP PRoject\Attendance\attend.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pyzbar .pyzbar import decode
  File "P:\Prashant\Python\Attendance\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\pyzbar.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .wrapper import (
  File "P:\Prashant\Python\Attendance\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\wrapper.py", line 151, in <module>
    zbar_version = zbar_function(
  File "P:\Prashant\Python\Attendance\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\wrapper.py", line 148, in zbar_function
    return prototype((fname, load_libzbar()))
  File "P:\Prashant\Python\Attendance\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\wrapper.py", line 127, in load_libzbar
    libzbar, dependencies = zbar_library.load()
  File "P:\Prashant\Python\Attendance\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\zbar_library.py", line 60, in load
    dependencies, libzbar = load_objects(Path(__file__).parent)
  File "P:\Prashant\Python\Attendance\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\zbar_library.py", line 54, in load_objects
    libzbar = cdll.LoadLibrary(str(directory.joinpath(fname)))
  File "C:\Users\kalep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 452, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Users\kalep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'P:\Prashant\Python\Attendance\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\libzbar-64.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

I am creating project on attendance system using QR Code scanning and I use Python to create it.
I used all needed libraries in the program
like, `cv2`, `numpy`, `pybase64`, `pyzbar`.

But I am getting this above Error in the Pyzbar.

Comment: I think that might be the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66792366/could-not-find-module-libiconv-dll-when-trying-to-import-pyzbar-module-into

Comment: it needs C/C++ library `libiconv.dll` which you may have to install manually - ie. [LibIconv](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm)

Comment: But this library is already present in the pyzbat library folder.I also give the folder path of libiconv.dll file....But this does not work

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for this issue. I was facing similar issue just installed Visual C++ 64 bit version on my computer and restarted. Choose between vcredist_x86.exe or vcredist_x64.exe based on your machine.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40784. Hope this solves your issue as well.